# Fire click event on header after sorting column

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I am using table sorter plugin on my table //http://tablesorter.com/docs/index.html

And I want fire an event on click of the header that after sorting the column, I am trying as below

```
$("tableId").tablesorter();

$("thead th").click(function () {
    alert("hi");
});
```

But want happens is my event fires first than plugin event, i want my event fire after the plugin's event...

Any Idea Plz...................

Comment: Try `$("thead th").trigger('click')`

Comment: Does trigger fires after all the other events on the same element?

Comment: As per [Docs](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/), Execute all handlers and behaviors attached to the matched elements for the given event type.

Answer (score 3):

With **jQuery 1.3+**  :

```
$( "thead th" ).live( "click", function() {
  alert( "hi" );
});
```

With **jQuery 1.4.3+** :

```
$( document ).delegate( "thead th", "click", function() {
  alert( "hi" );
});
```

With **jQuery 1.7+** :

```
$( document ).on( "click", "thead th", function() {
  alert( "hi" );
});
```

More here (http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Comment: Ya thats right but I want my event to execute last among all other events for the matched selector

Answer (score 2):

You can bind to the `sortEnd` event which triggers after the table has sorted ([demo](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-triggers.html); javascript is way at the bottom of the page):

```
$(function() { 
    $("table")
        .tablesorter()
        .bind("sortEnd",function() {
            alert("hi");
        });
});
```

I wouldn't fire another click event on the header within this event callback as you will create an infinite loop of clicking and sorting.

Also, in case you are interested, I have a [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/) with lots of improvements.

Comment: Do you really mean in your example that a semi-colon is followed by a full stop?

Comment: @BriceC. Fixed! Thanks!

Comment: Very good. I upvoted your answer for it is useful indeed.